# PDFBox rendering uses a lot of memory

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I'm converting PDF to PNG in separate threads. My concern is - it requires a lot of memory. I did the heap dump during the rendering:

[image: heap dump]

And the question is - is it standard situation when we have 3 objects in memory for each page of PDF document?
According to the heap dump:
int[],
BufferedImage,
IntegerInterleavedRaster.
Probably we can get rid of unnecessary data in memory somehow, for example not to create int[]? I tied to follow the recommendations from Apache PDFBox documentation, but it didn't help to reduce memory usage.

The code is pretty simple:

```
try (final InputStream instream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(file));
     final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(instream);) {

        final PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        final int pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pageCount);
        List<Future<Path>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
            futures.add(executor.submit(new ConvertPdfPageToPngCallable(pdfRenderer, page, destination)));
        }
        for (Future<Path> future: futures){
            try {
                retval.add(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                executor.shutdownNow();
                ...
            }
        }

private class ConvertPdfPageToPngCallable implements Callable<Path>{
 ...
@Override
public Path call() throws Exception {
        final BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, destination, 300);
        return Paths.get(destination);
 }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please share your PDF 2) mention what version PDFBox you're using 3) the source code of PDFBox is available so feel free to tell the devs (I'm one of them) where an int[] is created that isn't needed and we'll fix it! 4) IMHO this question isn't for this site. Basically you have the opinion that something in the 121068 LoC of PDFBox isn't the best and want to discuss this.

Comment: The easiest way to limit the amount of memory needed is to limit the number of tasks running by limiting the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pageCount);`to a maximum. You need to be aware that each page converted to a raster will be a large bitmap. As long as these are processed they are kept in memory. I'm not sure as it's possible to reduce the usage of e.g. `IntegerInterleavedRaster`as this is created internally by `BufferedImage`.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr unfortunately, I can't share the PDF file. I use 2.0.6 version of PDFBox. Thank you.

Comment: Then there's nothing that can be done. Besides, the int[] is likely part of the raster, which is part of the image. Try this code: `BufferedImage bim = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            System.out.println(bim.getRaster());
            System.out.println(bim.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getClass());` the data buffer of the raster is an int[].

Comment: If you're still working with PDFBox, update to the latest version (2.0.9). We've improved memory usage again.